# What code is more readable / fast to make sure a binary digit is always zero in an input

Tags: elm

Variant 1

```
convertToBinary digitsList =
                        digitsList
                            |> List.take 4
                            |> setLastDigitToZero
                            |> numberFromDigits

                    setLastDigitToZero digitsList =
                        Array.fromList digitsList
                            |> Array.set (lastIndex digitsList) 0
                            |> Array.toList

                    lastIndex digitsList =
                        List.length digitsList - 1
```

vs

Variant 2

```
                    convertToBinary digitList =
                        digitList
                            |> List.take 3
                            |> List.reverse
                            |> List.append [ 1 ]
                            |> List.reverse
                            |> numberFromDigits
```

What do you think? And most importantly why?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to set the least significant digit in a 4 bit number to zero. You do this by passing in arrays of digits, using array operations to set a digit to zero, and then reassemble the number.

This is going to be slow no matter how you do it.

The dramatically much faster way is keeping the numbers as integers and using bitwise operations:

```
clearLeastSignificantBit : Int -> Int
clearLeastSignificantBit n = Bitwise.and n 0x0E -- 00001110 in binary
```

This way:

```
clearLeastSignificantBit 15 == 14 -- 1111 -> 1110
clearLeastSignificantBit 10 == 10 -- 1010 -> 1010
clearLeastSignificantBit  3 ==  2 -- 0011 -> 0010
```

Since programmers are generally familiar with bitwise operations, this is quite readable.